# Java Jakarta Mail 2.0.0 OAuth 2.0: Still uses PLAIN authentication

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail

I want to access Outlook of Microsoft 365 with Java using XOAUTH2. In my working code for PLAIN authentication, I added

```java
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
```

but the debug log still shows PLAIN authentication:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 2.0.0
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [WgBSADAAUAAyADcAOABDAEEAMAAwADcANgAuAEMASABFAFAAMgA3ADgALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=xxxxx password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Just a guess (as I do not know the JavaMail API): Maybe do `properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", true)`?

Comment: No, the setProperty() method requires two strings, as opposed to the put() method.

Comment: Mark: Why did you edited the question? My question was solved long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution:

Normally you could set the properties "mail.imap.xxx" even für IMAPS connections, but in the case of XOAUTH, it looks as if it requires "mail.imaps.xxx" to be set.

New code:

```
Mail property mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable: true
Mail property mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms: XOAUTH2
Mail property mail.imaps.port: 993
Mail property mail.store.protocol: imaps
Mail property mail.imaps.partialfetch: false
Mail property mail.mime.decodetext.strict: false
Mail property mail.imaps.peek: true
Mail property mail.mime.charset: UTF-8
```

After setting all properties to "mail.imaps.xxx", the authentication used XOAUTH.